# How to delete iPhoto photos?

Tags: photos.app

I zipped my iPhoto library and am transferring that to S3. I then deleted the iPhoto library icon thing.

I'm pretty sure that didn't get rid of the library.

How do I find the previous iPhoto library and delete the contents?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would help if you clarified what you mean by deleting "the iphoto library icon thing". If you mean deleting the iPhoto library (presumably from your Pictures folder) with its characteristic icon, based on the iPhoto icon itself, then there's not much more to do. Empty the trash?

Comment: I ran a GrandPerspective search on my computer and do not see what I suspected as my old library.

Answer (score 0):

The iPhoto Library is in your Pictures Folder by default - i.e unless you moved it.

Comment: Of course.  I'm looking for the files left on my computer since deleting that. [don't suggest show package contents, that won't solve my problem].

Comment: If you deleted that, what files are you expecting to remain? And since you say I shouldn't, then I demand that you show package contents! Any package! Contents! Now!

Comment: I would up vote your previous comment but I don't have the reps.  It made me giggle.